# Writing a cron job using CodeIgniter CLI?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, cron, command-line-interface

Hi I am facing some problems in writing a cron job using `CI CLI` way. My application has a controller name called `manager.php` in that there is method called check_status where I am gonna get all the `order_ids` using one model function. Ever order_id row had a status filed in database which either success or failure.

I have an api if i pass order_id to that it will tell whether order is successfully delivered or not. But here comes the problem I have below line in controller in the top.

```
<?php if(! defined('BASEPATH') ) exit("NO Direct Script Access Allowed"); ?>
```

So when i try to run method `check_status` from CLI in CI it gives me an error stating `NO Direct Script Access Allowed`.

This is the way i called above method `php application/controllers/manager.php check_status`

So i decided like this i created an another class file called cron_job.php in that i didn't keep the above error line  `"No Direct Script Access Allowed"`. I thought it will give access now when i try to run but it doesn't give an error and even output also.

This is the class which i created and method in that.

```
<?php
class Cron_job extends CI_Controller {

    public function message($to = 'World')
    {
        echo "Hello {$to}!".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

I run this controller form CLI like this `php application/controller/cron_job.php message`

```
Note: I am in ROOT directory.
```

No Output at all. So i tried in another way like this `php index.php application/controller/cron_job.php message`

Now it gives me error stating that `Error 404 page not found.`

What i tried in another way now i created a  file in views folder and in that i am calling old controller/method url like below.

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://application_path/controller/method");

echo $result;
```

Now i am getting output which i defined in the method check_status in manager.php controller.

But here comes another problem now after the above line i will get an array output which had all the order_ids.

I am gonna send this each id to a api to check status. If it is failure it will check whether it is delivered or not. If it's done i need to update that status in the database against that order_id. But now i am in view file, is it possible to call a model file from the view file or is there any way to do this.

Any help?

Note: There is no syntax errors in any controller or any method , which are fully verified and working normally when i am accessing using urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ci helper will help you in this.

1 ) Create a helper & create a function in it, that calls your model function

```
function getUserDetails($userId = '') {
  $CI = & get_instance(); 
  $getUserDetailsByUserId = $CI->user_model->getUserDetailsByUserId($userId);
  return $getUserDetailsByUserId;
}
```

2) Now you can call `getUserDetails($userId);` in your view.

Comment: Hi right now i am able to get status from api now i want to use that status to update it in the database. I loaded helper file in my view like this $CI = & get_instance(); $CI->load->helper('generic'); Then there is a method in the helper update_status($status) so i am calling this method from my view file after loading helper like this  update_status($status)....but nothing is happening.

Comment: load helper in your controller.
simply. 

$this->load->helper('generic');

and call update_status($status); in view.

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the CodeIgniter help section on [Running via the Command Line](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html). It's very easy. Your original approach was correct. But you do not call your controller method directly by its path, instead CD to your project root and then the call the index.php file with the controller and method as parameters.

```
// This is how you call CI via the command line.
// Use spaces between index.php and your arguments.
$ php index.php <controller> <method> [params]

// And in your instance
$ php index.php manager check_status [param1 param2 param3]
```

Depending on your host you may need to call the PHP version compiled for CLI.